# Convert R RNA-seq data object to a Python object

Tags: rna-seq, r, python

I have done some work in R and would like to try a Python tool.

What is a good way to **import** the data (and its annotations etc) **as a Python object?**

I am particularly interested in converting a `Seurat` object into an [AnnData](https://scanpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/scanpy.api.AnnData.html#scanpy.api.AnnData) object. (Either directly or as a Python object which can be converted into an `AnnData`.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A simple solution for converting Seurat objects into AnnData, [as described in this vignette](https://satijalab.org/seurat/conversion_vignette.html):

```
library(reticulate)
seuratobject_ad <- Convert(from=seuratobject, to="anndata", filename="seuratobject.h5ad")
```

---

Alternatively, one can use [Loom](http://loompy.org/), *"a file format designed to store and work with single-cell RNA-seq data".*

In R, install [LoomR](http://satijalab.org/loomR/loomR_tutorial.html):

```
devtools::install_github(repo = "mojaveazure/loomR")
```

Convert from Seurat object to loom:

```
pfile <- Convert(from = pbmc_small, to = "loom", filename = "pbmc_small.loom")
pfile$close() # close loom objects when finished using them.
```

Then import loom object in Python using [loompy](http://linnarssonlab.org/loompy/index.html), or directly as AnnData:

[`scanpy.api.read_loom`](http://scanpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/scanpy.api.read_loom.html)

---

Alternatively, see [`feather`](https://github.com/wesm/feather).

---

[Or export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46390461/the-best-way-to-import-r-object-into-python) as some text format (csv, json) then import into Python.

Comment: I would recommend to follow the KISS rule. If you can export the data in .csv or json better, but that depends on what is the original data format

Answer (score 0):

The accepted solution is probably the best for older objects of type `seurat` created with Seurat package v2. For newer `Seurat Objects`, there is a new tool designed specifically for this purpose, called [`SeuratDisk`](https://mojaveazure.github.io/seurat-disk/articles/convert-anndata.html).

There is a nicely documented vignette about the [Seurat <-> AnnData conversion](https://mojaveazure.github.io/seurat-disk/articles/convert-anndata.html). In short:

1. In R, save the Seurat object as an h5Seurat file:

```
library(Seurat)
library(SeuratDisk)

SaveH5Seurat(SeuratObject, filename = "file.h5Seurat")
Convert("file.h5Seurat", dest = "h5ad")
```

2. In python, simply load the file:

```py
import scanpy

adata = scanpy.read_h5ad("file.h5Seurat")
```

Answer (score 0):

Since both Seurat and Scanpy are evolving rapidly, the safest way is to
[save your Seurat object into MatrixMarket format + metadata csv](https://github.com/brianpenghe/Seurat3-plus/blob/master/Seurat_to_MM10X.R), and
[import them into Scanpy](https://scanpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/scanpy.read_10x_mtx.html).